# Eclipse 3.8.1 - hiding external jars from the project view

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

The title more or less says it, I think.

In earlier versions of Eclipse - windows or linux - when I've imported external jars, these haven't been visible in the project view, along with the packages, sources and other resources.

Now, in Eclipse 3.8.1, in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, this has changed. When I import some 50 external jars in my project, all of these are listed in the project view, cluttering the windows unnecessarily.

I've been looking in the settings and preferences, but I cannot see a way to hide them. Anyone know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In package explorer, little triangle on right and:

Filters -> Select: Libraries from external

Comment: Thanks. ALLMOST; it turned out to be the little triangle -> Customize View, then select "Libraries from External".